# jQuery Validator validating two formats on same field

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, date-format

I have a form with multiple date fields each with unique name and id field. I want to validate the date as **dd/mm/yyyy**. I am using a `php codeigniter` based cms **fuelcms** which auto generates date fields with validator's data attributes. I have set the rule to validate for dateITA format (dd/mm/yyyy), but when I put a date it seems to check for two formats:

1. dd/mm/yyyy
2. mm/dd/yyyy

I don't know what's causing the issue, since I have disabled my rule so now it is validating against **mm/dd/yyyy** and I don't know where it is setting that rule because the default is dateISO (yyyy-mm-dd).

How can I achieve the desired effect?

#### HTML

```
<input type="text" name="date_of_birth" value="" 
    class="datepicker field_type_date date hasDatepicker" size="12" 
    placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required="" data-date_format="dd/mm/yy" 
    data-first_day="0" data-show_on="focus" id="date_of_birth" autocomplete="bday" 
    aria-required="true">
```

#### JS

```
$('#job-form').validate({
    errorClass:'small text-danger',
    rules: {
        date_of_birth: {
            dateITA: true
        }
    }
});
```

`#job-form` is the id of form

Comment: Start by showing us the relevant code.  Also please do a better job narrowing this down and explaining it.  Are you having an issue with client-side validation or server-side validation?

Comment: I am having issue on client side validation and I have default scripts used to enable validation like `jquery.validate({ rules: { id: { dateITA: true } } })`

Comment: Then edit the OP with enough code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Added code please look at it

Comment: If this is about client-side validation, then you should not have tagged this question with server-side languages or technologies.  Edited tags.

Comment: yes but it's also coming from the cms I'm using

Comment: Are you saying that your CMS is automatically writing all the JavaScript that you've posted here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172719/discussion-between-ateebahmed-and-sparky).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

[jsfiddle.net/vomu9rf7](https://jsfiddle.net/vomu9rf7)

`12/12/2018` is valid but both `31/12/2018` and `12/31/2018` are not valid.  This is because your inline `class` attribute contains `date`, which automatically triggers the `date` method of jQuery Validate.  Since you're also declaring `dateITA`, the plugin is applying two different date rules simultaneously to your field... `date` and `dateITA` which are in conflict with each other.

Remove the `date` class, and the `dateITA` rule is working fine:

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/r1kwjv35/](https://jsfiddle.net/r1kwjv35/)**

Comment: Thanks, how can I do that? as this field is auto generated by the cms I'm using. jquery? after rendering?

Comment: @ateebahmed, you have not shown any server-side CMS code that controls what is being rendered.   Refer to the documentation for the CMS and see how to control the inline classes that are rendered.

Comment: used jquery to edit classes and it seems to work, thanks